# Firebase Cloud Function and React Native

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-functions, expo

I would like to know if it was possible to execute a function from Firebase Cloud Function on a React Native Expo application (using the SDK)? I tried to install the sdk but I get several errors.
If not, is there another way to do it, without the SDK?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you do not want to install any third party module, then use react native's `fetch` API:

A simple `GET` operation would be:

```
fetch('<Your Firebase Cloud Function URL>')
```

A `POST` operation would be done this way:

```
fetch('<Yout Firebase Cloud Function URL>', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        ...
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
        ...
    })
})
```

Or, there are some popular 3rd party libraries such as `axios`. Install it using command `npm i --save axios` and then:

```
import axios from 'axios'

axios.get('<Your Firebase Cloud Function URL>')
```

or

```
axios.post('<Your Firebase Cloud Function URL>', {
    ...
    ...
})
```

Comment: I have some function it gets our nearby user and i wrote them in client side and when the app will be growth it's taken time to get the results and slow the performance, so i want to move them to firebase cloud function, but now how to handle the results of the function? I.e save the results in real-time database and request to retrieve the data saved, or what?

Comment: @DevAS Send the results back to the client side. Your cloud function starts with something like this right? `exports.someFunction = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => { // Do whatever you need to do to get the results; return res.status(200).send(...) }`

Comment: @K.Wu I'm faced the same as @DevAs want .. but I can't understand this `/ Do whatever you need to do to get the results` I just get users from DB then use third party package to handle it in Client-side how can I handle it with Cloud Functions

Comment: @OliverD Yours is a separate question, which cannot be answered with a short comment and it is against SO community's rules to post another answer below, as it's irrelevant to the original question. If you would post a new question and pin me the link, I can take a look